# Shifting roots in infinite sums of polynomials

Tags: real-analysis, generating-functions, residue-calculus, rationality-testing

Define

$$P(n)=(n-r_1)(n-r_2)...(n-r_k)$$

where $r_i\in\mathbb{Q}$ and $r_i\neq r_j$ for $i\neq j$. Now, define

$$Q(n)=(n-(r_1+m))(n-r_2)...(n-r_k)$$

where $m\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $r_1+m\neq r_j$ for $1<j\leq k$. If we know

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{P(n)}\in\mathbb{Q}$$

and $r_1+m\not\in\mathbb{N}$, does that imply

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{Q(n)}\in\mathbb{Q}?$$

For example, it can be shown that

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(n-\frac{1}{2})(n-\frac{5}{2})}=-\frac{4}{3}\ \text{ while }\ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(n-(\frac{1}{2}+1))(n-\frac{5}{2})}=-\frac{3}{2}.$$

The motivation for this problem is that I found a link between my last [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2923680/if-sum-n-1-infty-frac1pn-in-mathbbq-is-sum-n-1-infty-fra) on this site and this problem. That is, if one could prove this, then they would prove the other question (the easier one about simple roots). Overall, I have tried to work through this problem using residues and generating functions. Any tips, terms, papers, methods, or generally topics that I could look into would also be welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question as I finally found what I strongly believe to be a counterexample:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\left(n+\frac{1}{3}\right) \left(n+\frac{5}{6}\right) \left(n+\frac{11}{6}\right) \left(n+\frac{7}{3}\right)}=\frac{9}{154}$$

$$\text{but }\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\left(n+\frac{1}{3}\right) \left(n+\frac{5}{6}\right) \left(n+\frac{11}{6}\right) \left(n+\frac{7}{3}+1\right)}=\frac{-39033+12320 \sqrt{3} \pi -36960 \log (2)}{51975}.$$

Of course, it might possibly be the case that the number on the right is rational, but I have neither the time nor the will to prove so (in fact, I believe it is an open question whether $\log(r)$ and $\pi$ for $r\in\mathbb{Q}$ are algebraically independent), since it is widely believed $\log(r)$ and $\pi$ are algebraically independent. This is the same probable counterexample that I gave [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2923680/if-sum-limits-n-1-infty-frac1pn-in-mathbbq-is-sum-limits-n-1). In fact, these two propositions are equivalent (even if they both are false) which I did prove.

Comment: I'm confused. How do you know this is a counterexample? You said the number on the right might be rational...

Comment: The only reason I said it could be rational is because I do not have a proof that it is irrational (although I strongly suspect it is). In fact, I believe the algebraic independence of $\pi$ and $\log(r)$ for rational $r$ is still an open problem.

Comment: so you don't know it is a counterexample. I'm just saying you should edit your answer to reflect this. I of course agree it is overwhelmingly likely it is a counterexample

Comment: I'm sorry; I had to edit. You do not know whether it is a counterexample, so I had to edit to convey that.

Comment: That's a good point, fair edit